# How to access Pandas series value in a custom function

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I'm working on a project to monitor my 5k time for my running/jogging activities based on their GPS data. I'm currently exploring my data in a Jupyter notebook & now realize that I will need to exclude some activities.

Each activity is a row in a dataframe. While I do want to exclude some rows, I don't want to drop them from my dataframe as I will also use the df for other calculations.

I've added a column to the df along with a custom function for checking the invalidity reasons of a row. It's possible that a run could be excluded for multiple reasons.

```
In []:
    # add invalidity reasons column & update logic
    df['invalidity_reasons'] = ''
    
    def maintain_invalidity_reasons(reason):
        """logic for maintaining ['invalidity reasons']"""
        reasons = []
        if invalidity_reasons == '':
            return list(reason)
        else:
            reasons = invalidity_reasons
            reasons.append(reason)
            return reasons
```

I filter down to specific rows in my df and pass them to my function. The below example returns a set of five rows from the df. Below is an example of using the function in my Jupyter notebook.

```
In []:
    columns = ['distance','duration','notes']
    
    filt = (df['duration'] < pd.Timedelta('5 minutes'))
    df.loc[filt,columns].apply(maintain_invalidity_reasons('short_run'),axis=1)

Out []:
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-107-0bd06407ef08> in <module>
          2 
          3 filt = (df['duration'] < pd.Timedelta('5 minutes'))
    ----> 4 df.loc[filt,columns].apply(maintain_invalidity_reasons(reason='short_run'),axis=1)
    
    <ipython-input-106-60264b9c7b13> in maintain_invalidity_reasons(reason)
          5     """logic for maintaining ['invalidity reasons']"""
          6     reasons = []
    ----> 7     if invalidity_reasons == '':
          8         return list(reason)
          9     else:
    
    NameError: name 'invalidity_reasons' is not defined
```

Here is an example of the output of my filter if I remove the .apply() call to my function

```
In []:
columns = ['distance','duration', 'notes','invalidity_reasons']

filt = (df['duration'] < pd.Timedelta('5 minutes'))
df.loc[filt,columns]

Out []:
```

[image: output of filtered dataframe]

It seems that my issue lies in not knowing how to specify that I want to reference the scalar value in the 'invalidity_reasons' index/column (not sure of the proper term) of the specific row.

I've tried adjusting the `IF` statement with the below variants. I've also tried to apply the function with/out the axis argument. I'm stuck, please help!

```
if 'invalidity_reasons' == '':
if s['invalidity_reasons'] == '':
```

Comment: This is code soup. `invalidity_reasons` is not defined anywhere before it is used,  and `list(reason)` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: I believe you regarding the `list(reason)` issue. Once I determine how to properly access the value in the series (i.e. the row), I should be able to troubleshoot it further.

`invalidity_reasons` is a df column that I create before I begin any filtering of the df. It's mentioned in the first line of the first code block in my post (just beneath the comment). For each row, the initial of `invalidity_reasons` is an empty string until I need to update it with my function.

Comment: Also, I'm a bit new to Python & Pandas so I'll gladly accept any feedback regarding how to improve my code soup.

Comment: This `if 'invalidity_reasons' == ''` doesn't make sense (will always be `False`). And, as cs95 has pointed out, you have no _variable_ named `invalidity_reasons`. The fact that your frame has a column with that name doesn't make that happen.

Comment: `invalidity_reasons` isn't supposed to be a variable but rather the index/label of a scalar value in each series (i.e. row) that I'm passing to my function. To clarify my intention I've updated my post with an example of the output of my filter without the .apply() call to show what data I want my function to act upon.

Comment: to be super clear, what I want to do is:
1. pass a row or set of rows to a function
2. for each row, I want the function to:
     1. find the value of a specific index/label in the row
     2. update said value based on it's current value (i.e. if blank/empty/null: do x; else: do y)

Comment: _"`invalidity_reasons` isn't supposed to be a variable"_ -- but in your code you use it as if it is a variable and that's the source of your (current) error: "NameError: name 'invalidity_reasons' is not defined".

Comment: that's my question, how can I specify that I want to reference the scalar value of the series? I've tried changing how I reference it in the `IF` statement to no avail.

Both of the alternatives I mention in the post also result in a NameError.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty much a stab in the dark, but I hope it helps. In the following I'm using this simple frame as an example (to have something to work with):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col': range(5)})
```

Now if you define

```
def maintain_invalidity_reasons(current_reasons, new_reason):
    if current_reasons == '':
        return [new_reason]
    if type(current_reasons) == list:
        return current_reasons + [new_reason]
    return [current_reasons] + [new_reason]
```

add another column `invalidity_reasons` to `df`

```
df['invalidity_reasons'] = ''
```

populate one cell (for the sake of exemplifying)

```
df.loc[0, 'invalidity_reasons'] = 'a reason'
```

```
   Col invalidity_reasons
0    0           a reason
1    1                   
2    2                   
3    3                   
4    4
```

build a filter

```
filt = (df.Col < 3)
```

and then do

```
df.loc[filt, 'invalidity_reasons'] = (df.loc[filt, 'invalidity_reasons']
                                        .apply(maintain_invalidity_reasons,
                                               args=('another reason',)))
```

you will get

```
   Col          invalidity_reasons
0    0  [a reason, another reason]
1    1            [another reason]
2    2            [another reason]
3    3                            
4    4
```

Does that somehow resemble what you are looking for?

Comment: yes, that's what I needed. I think the biggest part of my problem was that I didn't have an argument in my function to represent the series itself (`current_reasons` in your function). Thank you for your patience & assistance!